# how can we write css code without browser detection

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, user-agent, browser-detection

I read this article and i wonder. http://www.quirksmode.org/js/support.html

How can we write css codes without user-agent detection for only a browser (only firefox, chrome etc.)

Comment: This is covered at exhaustive lengths throughout other questions. Just look for "CSS hacks".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876156/css-hacks-firefox-3-5-and-google-chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to write the code for browser detection if you let a **tool** like [modernizr.js](http://www.modernizr.com/) do it for you. Or use a CSS "**reset**" file such as [this one](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/). With those approaches, you can focus on functionality and not browser incompatibilities.