# Import css file if chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, conditional-statements

How do I import an css file for Chrome (or webkit).

I want to do something like this for ie6:

```
<!--[if lte IE 6]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876156/css-hacks-firefox-3-5-and-google-chrome does possible answer your question

Comment: Why would you want to do such a thing?  Chrome is a grade A browser (see:  http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/tutorials/gbs/)

Comment: I'm using .net c# so I used did it this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715806/load-different-css-file-based-on-browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best, and easiest, bet is using a server-side language that can detect the user's browser. PHP, ColdFusion, JSP, etc have built-in functions and variables that can help you determine the browser a user has.

If not, then a client-side scripting agent is your next option. JavaScript, and its efficient library option, jQuery, are good approaches.

```
 //jQuery
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script>
        if ($.browser.webkit) {
            ///Chrome-specific css here.
        }
       </script>
```

If you can't (or don't know how to) use the library, then the following works as well, but you'll need to do a few more conditional checks

```
//Javascript (Note: Chrome will say 'Netscape' for its name)
    <script>
    var browserName = window.navigator.appName;
    var browserVersion = window.navigator.appVersion;
    </script>
```

Comment: I'm using .net c# so I used did it this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715806/load-different-css-file-based-on-browser

Answer (score 0):

if you want to only change lines of code instead load a full css file you could use this:
http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/